# Can I disable a plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: plugins, eclipse

I have a plugin that I use regularly for months at a time, but for the next couple of months, I will not need it at all.  I believe that this plugin makes Eclipse very slow, so I would like to disable it.  I don't want to uninstall it, because I will need to use it again in a couple months (and it is possible something will come up and I will need it occasionally sooner than that).

So, is it possible to disable an Eclipse plugin, without uninstalling it?

***EDIT***:
I have read through the link posted by @SleighBoy, but I don't seem to have the menu options mentioned:

[image: Eclipse Help Menu]

Comment: You're using MyEclipse, not Eclipse.

Comment: @SlieghBoy I am using Eclipse with the MyEclipse plugin.  (MyEclipse is not the plugin I am trying to disable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Help > Install New Software
2. Click the **What is already installed?** link in the right lower area

That will get you where you need to be.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Would you mind editing your answer to include the relevant quote from that page?  That way, if the Eclipse Wiki changes its structure, and someone lands on this question in the future, they won't just be left with a dead link.

Comment: @pkaeding Is your Eclipse version older than the current stable release? I think I remember they moved the plugin configuration around a few releases ago.

Comment: He is using MyEclipse ( http://www.myeclipseide.com/ ), so I guess it differs. The change you're referring to changed between 3.1 and 3.2 I think.